# Good qualities of ovens/microwaves for baking cake

Tags: baking, equipment

My aunt wants to start her own bakery where she is planning to sell different kinds of biscuits, cakes, and desserts. But she cannot afford to buy an industrial oven right now as she wants to start small.

So my questions are,

- What types of oven (traditional, convection, convection-microwave, etc.) are best for commercial scale baking (especially cakes)?
- What are the most important qualities of a commercially available oven/microwave for good, consistent baking results?

Comment: You may want to see [this Q/A](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19975/uneven-baking-in-a-convection-microwave-oven?rq=1) about convection microwave ovens.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But that question only answers that we cannot expect good result from convection microwave oven. Which just discard convection microwave from my list. Can you please recommend which one is good for baking? I am editing my question.

Comment: This is why I gave you the link: for further information instead of closing as a duplicate.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Unfortunately your question is off-topic as it's both too broad and opinion based. There are many ovens and what is available is dependent on your location, what she can buy is limited to budget.

Comment: @GdD Thanks for the review. For your information, I didn't want to have a product recomendation(not like LG-MS3200) but an equipment recomendation (like what type of oven should I buy like `Toaster oven: because it provide heat evenly`) which I thought would be okay to ask as asking about `kitchen equipment` is okay by the the `help center`. Let me know please if I misunderstand anything.

Comment: I'm going to +1 this, because my initial reaction is "if she wants to sell baked goods, not way she's going to be able to make something people will want to buy with any kind of microwave" - but then it occurs to me that I am, in no way, a baking expert. It will be interesting to see my assumptions challenged or validated.

Comment: @GdD I read this question as “what type of domestic oven is best suited for this specific use case”, asking for characteristics of different oven types. This should be answerable based on technical details, not just opinion?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not going to claim this is an exhaustive list, especially as I'm not a commercial baker, but a few things that I would personally consider:

What is she baking?  What size vessels does it need?  How tall does it rise? This will affect how can she fit in the oven at one time (how many per shelf, how many shelves for the height it needs).  Note that you don't want to pack them too closely, as you need space around them, even for convection.

What is the largest sheet pan it can fit with a couple of inches (5+ cm) around each side?

If electric, how much power does she have available?  (will it require getting an electrician in to run heavier wire?)

I'd also look to see if there are any places that deal in used restaurant equipment.  In the US, restaurants have a rather high failure rate, and there are places that specialize in liquidating restaurants / auctioning off everything in them.

Answer (score 0):

A good thermostat which will hold correct temperature for long time is the most important thing, but I don't know how you can check that.

Comment: I was thinking of that, but I don't think it's that important. My own aunt had a successful bakery business using a traditional wood fired oven. No thermostat,  temperature changing constantly. Some the good home bakers I know also have ovens with very bad thermostats. Especially for somebody doing commercial, it is less important than for normal home use. As a bakery, you don't try new recipes all the time, you gather enough experience to make your recipe work with your oven's idiosyncrasies. Especially since bad thermostats don't "jump around", they have a constant offset.

Comment: You have issues with 'precision' vs. 'accuracy'.  An inaccurate oven might be 50 degrees off ... and if you know that, you're fine and can correct for.  An imprecise oven is bad, as you don't know how far off it is at any given time.  Most are imprecise to some degree (wait 'til the temperature drops below a lower threshold, heat back up 'til you hit a higher threshold,etc.).  It's the precision that you have to be careful about ... and how evenly it heats if it's not convection.